# Change some CSS values with no transition and then immediately after that change with transition

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

Here is the situation:

I have an element which have to be moved to some place on click without a transition and then immediately moved to another but now with the transition.

First, I tried like so:

```
var transform = Modernizr.prefixed('transform'),
    transition = Modernizr.prefixed('transition'),
    style1 = {},
    style2 = {};

style1[transform] = "translate(100px, 20px)";
style1[transition] = "none"; 
style2[transform] = "translate(500px, 50px)";
style2[transition] = "2s"; 

$('div')
    .on('click', function () {
        $(this)
          .css(style1)
          .css(style2);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trajektorijus/vUUb5/2/

But that didn't do the trick... Can someone explain why?

I managed to do what I wanted, but I don't think it's the right way to do that:

```
var transform = Modernizr.prefixed('transform'),
    transition = Modernizr.prefixed('transition'),
    style1 = {},
    style2 = {};

style1[transform] = "translate(100px, 20px)";
style1[transition] = "none"; 
style2[transform] = "translate(500px, 50px)";
style2[transition] = "2s"; 

$('div')
    .on('click', function () {
        $(this)
            .css(style1)
            .delay()
            .queue(function () {
                $(this)
                    .css(style2)
                    .dequeue();
            });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trajektorijus/vUUb5/3/

Can you suggest something smarter than this?

Thanks!

EDIT: Another option would be:

```
var $this = $(this);

$this.css(style1);
setTimeout(function () { $this.css(style2); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trajektorijus/vUUb5/5/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/vUUb5/4/

```
$(function () {
    $('div').on('click', function () {
        $(this).css({top: '20px', left: '100px' })
            .animate({ top: '50px', left: '500px' }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but i must use translate.